# Pickup truck run on boards, under boards are gravel driveway

Tags: meaning-in-context

From "[The pros and cons of delaying college](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/projects/cp/national/college-applications/the-pros-and-cons-of-delaying-college)" by Anemona Hartocollis in *The New York Times*, October 25, 2016:

> The gravel driveway to the farm is marked by stars and stripes painted on boards, like a Jasper Johns painting, with a baby’s footprints where the stars should be. Its whimsy hints at the affectionate family life inside. In the kitchen, the grocery list on the chalkboard shows requisitions, in different handwriting, for “man soap” and “sanity.” Well-seasoned cast iron pans hang on the wall, and in a freewheeling spirit, nobody minds that the bathroom has no door.

Pieces of boards are printed with Stars and Stripes, and cars run on the boards. Why will the gravel driveway be paved with boards? Pickup trucks will be difficult to run on, won't they? What is the size of each board? It fails to come to my mind how it looks like. Is it a typical one for Kansas farms? I have never been American farm nor America. I prefer a picture of it to understand it better.

Comment: The gravel driveway isn't ***paved with*** boards, it's ***marked by*** boards. I don't know exactly what this means, but I'm quite sure that cars will have gravel, and not boards, under their wheels.

Comment: I'd imagine that several of the boards are on posts where the driveway turns off from the road. They mark the turning into the drive.

Comment: Thank you as I am clear now. "Mark" as I looked up dictionary , should mean "To single out or indicate by". Many thanks! To Peter and Spagirl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The gravel driveway to the farm is **marked** by stars and stripes painted on boards*

Here the verb **[to mark](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mark)** means (scroll down to the "British definitions" section):

> 27. to set boundaries or limits

So presumably there are boards along the side of the gravel, which define the limits of the driveway.